# A recommended Ruby interactive console

Tags: ruby, shell

I'm looking for a good Ruby interactive shell. The shell I'm looking for must have the following features:

1. autocompletion
2. syntax highlighting
3. smart ident
4. previous command retrieval
5. automatic display of function arguments
6. automatic display of function documentation
7. works on Windows
8. fast and responsive

The shell I'm looking for would have been nice had it featured the following:

1. automatic completion of file names
2. automatically adds parenthesis when coding a function call
3. a division of the window into a history box (with previous commands and their outputs) and a code box (where I write my code). [DreamPie](http://dreampie.sourceforge.net/) is an example of a Python shell which features that concept.

Any suggestions for such a Ruby interactive shell?

Comment: isnt a good text editor with console + run env better ?

Answer (score 3):

The two main ruby shells that exist currently are [irb](http://ruby-doc.org/docs/ProgrammingRuby/html/irb.html) and [pry](http://pryrepl.org/), neither of which accomplishes all of your requirements. Also, you may be able to fulfill more of your needs using an IDE like [RubyMine](http://www.jetbrains.com/ruby/) or by hacking on a plugin to a text editor like [Sublime](http://www.sublimetext.com/).

Having a fully capable ruby shell like this could be great for the community. Drop a link if you're working on one :)